# How to delete the date of photo album in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I want to delete the date of a particular album, but I can't. I can only delete the month and day, but the year is still there? How to delete it completely?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way natively or otherwise to do this.